# Lifetime of Pre-Release Orgs for Partners to test APEX and Managed Packages?

Tags: apex, managed-package, partner, developer-edition, pre-release

We have some pre-release orgs on the gs0 pod. All of them are Developer Editions. I noticed that one of them I've spun in 2014 is still available, while an other one I've spun around 2015 is gone.

We use these Orgs to pre-test some managed packages and/or APEX code and/or webservice-integrations against the new releases/APIs in advance, to avoid unexpected behavior.

Reading through the Partner Community (https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerAlert?id=a033000000FnqznAAB), I found this:

> What do I need to know about partner pre-release orgs? Partner
>   pre-release orgs are available for the following Salesforce editions:
>   Group, Professional, Enterprise, and Developer. Additionally, partner
>   pre-release orgs are:
>
> - Net-new. These pre-release orgs will not contain data from your other Salesforce orgs.
> - Available for testing only.
> - Not intended for development purposes. **Your pre-release Developer Edition orgs and other pre-release orgs may be periodically deleted in
>     anticipation of the next release.**
> - Not intended for distribution. Consulting partners cannot use these orgs for customer-facing purposes, and ISVs cannot submit apps built
>     in them for Security Review or publish the apps on the AppExchange.

Does this mean, that org deletions are for us totally uncontrollable, unforeseeable and defacto random? Is there any way to prevent deletions of such org?

The reason I'm asking is, that the setup of a testing process for packages, processes or whatever can take an enormous effort to set it up (e.g. for pumping appropriate test-data via an ETL process, configuration, etc.). All that work will get wiped, if such a pre release Org has to be spun, dataloaded and configured per release again and again and again.

Is there a way to get more endurable pre-release Developer Editions?